# Autonumbring - Lastnumber used was edited

Tags: acumatica

Scenario -  CD field is defined with ISKey =true while in Database ID field is used as Primary key Key column
The CD field is bind with AutoNumbering sequence.

User generated multiple documents lets say from 0001 to 0034 now he come back to autonumbering sequence and changed the LastNumberUsed to 0001 again.

Now when the new document is created the latest number given is 0002 while this number is already used.

I think acumatica should not allow any document with the same key field even if the document is created by the code.
Please suggest.

Comment: Major Note - CD field is not the Key field at the Database.

Comment: We observe that if the CD field is the primary Key field in the Database then the Numbering sequence works as expected and skips the used number, but if the CD field is not the Primary key in Database and only in DAC it is defined with ISKey=True attribute then it allows the duplicate value by auto numbering sequence, that leads to menu other issues like Inquiry redirects to only first number not to the duplicate newly created number document etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my understanding, I can suggest two different methods for achieving this. You can try either of those approaches.

1. You can add PXUnique attribute to CD field which won't allow duplicates for the field to be saved.
2. You can validate the CD field for duplicates inside RowPersisting event which will ensure to not save any duplicate value in the field.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Acumatica will not allow to use the same number(Key field always unique) again. We can use any prefix in the last Number

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Iz8k.png)

Comment: Hi Jini, My issue is that, It is allowing the used number again,and My concern is that it should not allow.
How the last number got changed, from DB or from UI that I need to check ,
But at document level , it allows to retake the document already used number in the sequence.

Comment: Added Comment to original question for more details.